# creating dictionary from csv file with heading

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am new in python3 and need some help to solve the following exam.

There is a csv file:
id;name;Math;Programming;English;Art;driving license
1;Skye Davies;4.7293186886448;1.00694439962034;1.50237929698571;2;yes
2;Bailey Porter;2.04878889095744;2.80668511477619;1.06892193978582;4;
3;Brett West;3.69508976848625;1.28352644513587;2.89631143320307;3;

What I need to do, create a function `readdatabase(filename)`. This function has to read in the file and load the content to a temporary variable named `rawdata`.
Fill the `gradebook` variable and return it. This variable has to be a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains data of one student in the form

```
{"name":string,"id":integer,'driving license':bool,"Math":float,"English":int,"Art":int,"Programming":int,"passed":bool}
```

I have to loop over the `rawdata` variable, convert the data to the right types and assign them to the right key in the dictionary. The original file contains averages (floats) for each subject. Convert these to grades from 1-5. The only new field (not contained by the original file) is: "passed". This has to have a True value if the student has no '1' grade.

---

what I have now:

```
def readdatabase(filename):

    csvfile=open(filename,'r')
    csvreader = reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')

    rawdata=[] 
    for row in csvreader:
        rawdata.append(row)
    csvfile.close()

    keys=rawdata[0]
    gradebook=[]
```

## here I am in trouble to convert rawdata into gradebook dictionary. put first column into the dictionary but the rest I can't:

```
for column in rawdata:

    rawdata=[dict(zip(rawdata[0][column].split(';'), v[column].split(';'))) for v in rawdata[1:]]
```

## TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

```
    return gradebook


gradebook=readdatabase('gradebook.csv')
```

---

gradebook[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpV3y.png) should give this:

```
{'Art': 4,
 'English': 1,
 'Math': 2,
 'Programming': 3,
 'driving license': False,
 'id': 2,
 'name': 'Bailey Porter',
 'passed': False}
```

---

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Can you please post a *text* excerpt (as in copy and paste) of your csv, not a picture. That way we can use it ourselves. [Similar reasons to this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I used this to solve my exam:

def readdatabase(filename):

```
csvfile=open(filename,'r')
csvreader = reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
gradebook=[]

bl = 'Yes'    
next(csvreader)

for lines in csvfile:

    le=lines.split(';')
    ide=le[0]
    name=le[1]
    Math=round(float((le[2])))
    Programming=round(float((le[3])))
    English=round(float((le[4])))
    Art=int(le[5])
    driving=bl in (le[6])
    if Math > 1 and Programming > 1 and English > 1 and Art > 1:
        passed='True'
    else:
        passed="False"
    gradebook.append({"id":ide,"name":name,"Math":Math,"Programming":Programming,"English":English,"Art":Art, "driving license":driving, "passed":passed})

csvfile.close()


return gradebook
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to refer to the [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html?highlight=dictreader#csv.DictReader) class:

```
with open("myfile.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    data = [r for r in reader]
```

Then each item in `data` will be a dictionary.

Comment: in the end I used this code which works as expected: